# Reuse Hibernate Second Level Cache to Cache Instances in the Code?

Tags: hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

We have Infinispan 10.8.1 configured to work as a Hibernate second-level cache (2LC) in my Spring Boot application and it works as expected. The configuration is done in an infinispan.xml, with a transport configuration that points to a cluster.xml file that configures JGroups to setup a cluster of 4 machines using TCP.

We would like to use Infinispan in the code as well, to cache random instances that don't need to be persisted. However, we didn't find a way to reuse the same cache and cluster used by Hibernate, so the application does not end up creating a second cluster.

Pointing to the exact same configuration files used by Hibernate didn't prevent the application from creating a second cacheManager. How the existing cacheManager can be reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to dig into Hibernate (starting with an `org.hibernate.SessionFactory`) and extract the underlying cache manager like this:

```
    final SessionFactoryImpl factory = (SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory;
    final CacheImplementor cache = factory.getCache();
    final InfinispanRegionFactory regionFactory = (InfinispanRegionFactory)cache.getRegionFactory();
    final EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = regionFactory.getCacheManager();
```

Now you have a `cacheManager` you can call `cacheManager.createCache` to create your own cache, and then call `cache.put` and `cache.get`, etc.

This does a bit of unchecked casting and I would say it's very likely to change when you upgrade Hibernate or Ininispan in future.

An alternate way may be to extend `InfinispanRegionFactory` with your own version and override methods such that you can create your own caches at that point.  You will need to change configuration `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` to point at your class in this case.

Comment: Although possible, I would not reuse Infinispan caches in Hibernate for other uses, since the cache is configured particularly for that use case. The cache manager could be reused within a Spring Boot relatively safely though. In WildFly multiple cache managers can be built on top of a single JGroups cluster.

Comment: I agree messing with the hibernate caches is a bad idea. It seems ok to use the same cache manager, but with caches for other application features.